# ndk-build: command not found-mupdf compilation failed

Tags: android, android-ndk, mupdf

I'm trying to compile Mupdf. I followed the steps given in the mupdf documentation:
http://www.mupdf.com/docs/how-to-build-mupdf-for-android
But I'm getting a error at this step:
~/src/mupdf/platform/android $ ndk-build  -ndk-build: command not found

I have installed ndk-10. And I have given the path in eclipse. I followed below steps to give ndk path.

Window->Preferences->Android->ndk and i gave the path. But I'm not able to complete mupdf compilation. I'm not able to understand, what might have gone wrong. Is anyone facing a similar issue?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: show some code with layout.

Comment: Your thinking of issue bcz of viewHolder is wrong, bcz viewHolder is perfect for doing this, issue is with how you implementing, share some code so we can provide a solution.

Comment: Smartphone Developer- you are rite. View holder is perfect. there was problem in my implementation. I didn't check all conditions. Now It's working properly. Thanks for the reply..